# Problema de arrays y propiedades

Tags: javascript

necesito crear una funcion que reciba 2 parametros, el primero un arreglo de personas que contenga la informacion personal, entre ellas su edad, y como segundo parametro un numero que represente la edad limite que queres buscar. La funcion debera devolver un nuevo arreglo pero solo con las personas que tengan >= a la edad pasada como parametro.

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Leanne Graham",
      "username": "Bret",
      "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
      "age": 38,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Ervin Howell",
      "username": "Antonette",
      "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
      "age": 15,
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Clementine Bauch",
      "username": "Samantha",
      "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
      "age": 51,
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
      "username": "Karianne",
      "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
      "age": 56,
    },
console.log(mayoresDe(usuarios, 30));
deberia retornar todos los usuarios con >= a 30 de edad
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: aprende [ask], puede [edit] tu pregunta para subir un [example]

Answer (score 0):

Trataré de resolverle la duda tanto como pueda. Para trabajar con arrays JavaScript ofrece métodos muy útiles, tales como map, find, filter, etc. En este caso utilizar el método filter es muy útil, a continuación le explicaré el motivo. Yo escribiría la siguiente función:

```js
const mayoresDe = (personas, dato) => {
  return personas.filter(persona => persona.age >= dato)
}
```

[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) es un método para arrays que devuelve un array de elementos filtrados que recibe por parámetro una función con un parámetro, este parámetro representa cada elemento del array, cuando se ejecuta la función está debe devolver un valor booleano (true o false); en caso de que devuelva true ese elemento pertenece al array devuelto, en caso de que sea false, pues no.
Recomienda encadecidamente que se lea el link que le he adjuntado y visitar la documentación oficial de Mozilla que le proporcionará información más detallada y rigurosa. Espero que le haya servido esta información, así como espero que le haya podido solucionar la duda.
Un saludo.

Comment: Si bien es una respuesta completa, evita responder a preguntas en donde el autor de la misma no haya demostrado sus intentos en resolver su problema. [es.so] no es un sitio de tutoriales, ni un repositorio de código. Lee [answer], en especial la sección _contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_, y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

realice esta funcion pero solo me retorna la edad >= al parametro que le pase

```
function mayoresDe (info, edad) {
  
  let newInfo = [];
  let newAge = [];


  for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
    const element = info[i];
    newInfo.push(element);
    
    
    if(element.age >= edad) {
      newAge.push(element.age);
    }
    
  }
```

console.log(newInfo);
console.log(newAge);

}

console.log(mayoresDe(usuarios, 30));

Comment: Esta no es una respuesta, si necesitas agregar detalles a tu pregunta entonces edítala. Por favor has el [tour] y lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de ver tu código, básicamente en el array `new info` estás pegando una copia del array de personas, ya que a cada vuelta del bucle for estás agregando el respectivo elemento al array. Por otra parte estás agregando a un array aquellas edades que son superiores a `edad`. Si lo que deseas es implementar la funcionalidad de que la función imprima por consola los objetos que superen o sean igual a `edad`, yo me decantaría por un código más simple como el siguiente:

```js
function mayoresDe (info, edad) {
    const filtredPeople = []
    for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        const elem = info[i]
        if(elem.age >= edad) {
            filtredPeople.push(elem);
        }
    } 
    console.log(filtredPeople); 
}
```

En el que a cada vuelta de bucle revisamos la edad de elemento recorrido `info[i]` y si se cumple la condición de que `info[i]>=edad` entonces agregaremos el elemento actual: `info[i]` a un array, que posteriormente le imprimimos por consola.
Espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo.

Comment: Si necesitas agregar más información a tu respuesta deberías editarla y no crear una respuesta nueva. Por favor deja solo 1 respuesta

Comment: claro, es lo que hice en un principio pero faltaria que me muestre en consola la informacion completa de los usuarios que tienen >= edad 30, que no sabria como hacerlo

Comment: Una vez que tu tengas el array obtenido por la función no haría falta más que recorrerlo, e imprimir los datos que necesites. Recorres el array con un for e imprimes los datos con la sintaxis del punto, por ejemplo: info[i].name imprimiría el nombre del elemento que se está recorriendo.

Answer (score 0):

El metodo filter te ayuda a filtrar objetos de un array, y este devuelve un array nuevo con la conducion que especificas:

```
const arrayFinal = [
     {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Leanne Graham",
      "username": "Bret",
      "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
      "age": 38,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Ervin Howell",
      "username": "Antonette",
      "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
      "age": 15,
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Clementine Bauch",
      "username": "Samantha",
      "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
      "age": 51,
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
      "username": "Karianne",
      "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
      "age": 56,
    },
]
function a(array, edad){
  return array.filter( obj => obj.age >= edad )
}

console.log(a(arrayFinal,30));
```